# Lipschitz Continuity For a Vector Function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, vectors

I have a system of differential equations with 2 components.it looks like 
$\dot{X}=F(X)$  with some intial condition.
Note that both the vectors have two components.
I m trying to prove the existence of solution of the equation.
Therefore i want to prove F is Lipschitz continuous.
My problem is i don't know how Lipschitz continuity works for vector functions.
I am planning to show lipschitz continuity component-wise. But then I have trouble applying the Picards Lindlof theorem for existance as I know it for Simple Ordinary Differential Equations(Which have only one component).

Comment: $F$ is Lipschitz if there exist $M$ such that $\| F(x) - F(y) \| \le M \| x - y \|$. It's exactly like in $\Bbb R$, you just replace the modulus $| \cdot |$ with the norms $\| \cdot \|$ in the two vector spaces (domain and range). You apply Picard's and Lindelöf's theorem in exactly the same way.

Comment: You can choose a norm that suits (all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent). However, it may be the case that $F$ is a contraction with one norm and not another, so you need to choose carefully.

Comment: In most cases, you can show that $F$ has continuous partial derivatives (or bounded, or local bounded).